# Log query time in SQLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is there a way to log the duration of all queries performed on an SQLite database within an Application?

I have an application with a large database and I would like to get some insight into the time a query takes to be execute, and the time that the database is locked in a transaction.

Something like:

```
[10ms] select * from users where user_id = 10
[122ms] select * from users
```

I'm not looking to run 'explain' to identify potentially slow queries, I'd like to see how long queries are taking on a real device and find out if queries are being blocked from execution because another thread has locked the database.

The SQLiteDatabase class is final, so I could write a wrapper to manage the logging, but I was wondering if this has already been done or if there is a better approach.

The logging is only required during development. I am not interested in using this in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite for Android has a built-in support for that.

From [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDebug.java#L56):

```
/**
 * Controls the printing of wall-clock time taken to execute SQL statements
 * as they are executed.
 *
 * Enable using "adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteTime VERBOSE".
 */
public static final boolean DEBUG_SQL_TIME =
        Log.isLoggable("SQLiteTime", Log.VERBOSE);
```

Therefore, to enable execution time tracing run:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteTime VERBOSE
```

You will have to restart your application for reloading new settings**. Right afterwards you will start to see these log records in logcat:

> 02-14 12:27:00.457 11936-12137/osom.info.dbtest I/Database:
>   elapsedTime4Sql|/data/data/osom.info.dbtest/databases/test.db|1.000
>   ms|UPDATE TestTable SET key=? WHERE _id=1

** Sometimes this won't be enough, so run `adb shell stop` and `adb shell start`.

To stop printing these logs either restart the device (this property is not persisted between reboots) or set the property to a higher log level, i.e.:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteTime ERROR
```

Answer (score -2):

u can use this function in SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
public static Cursor query(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getInstance().getReadableDatabase();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsed = start - end;

    Log.v("SLOW_QUERIES", "Time elapsed: " + elapsed+ " SQL: " + sql);
    return cursor;
}
```