# How to identify slow queries in SQLite

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-room

I have a Room database with many Relations within Relations. It's not the best performance but it's getting worse with:

> **The connection pool for database xxx has been unable to grant a connection to thread xxx**

Based on some threads here I tried to investigate which queries are slowing my database down most.
I already found a promising ideas within SQLite like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022059/log-query-time-in-sqlite-on-android).
But unfortunately the queries Room creates are too long for logcat so I can't see how much time some of the queries take.

I investigated deeper and found [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDebug.java).

```
* For example, "adb shell setprop db.log.slow_query_threshold 200" will
* log all queries that take 200ms or longer to run.

public static final boolean shouldLogSlowQuery(long elapsedTimeMillis) {
```

I tried "adb shell setprop db.log.slow_query_threshold 200" but got

**failed to set property 'db.log.slow_query_threshold' to '200'**

Is there anything I have to do in order to get it to work or is there any other option I can try?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. i think your question _might_ need to be a bit more focused. if you want to know why a specific command is failing, then you should ask about that and only about that. if you're asking for ways to determine slow queries, you should ask about that specifically, at the moment your question seems a bit between the two of these, but that's just my opinion, either way, hope you find an answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My problem that one issue leads to another. Of course I want to fix the connection pool error but I only could find suggestions to clean up queries. Therefore I kept my original problem in there hoping that someone maybe has another idea what I can try if setting the threshold is not working.